# Should I just be using std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I've created a function that takes in an array with a unknown size. 
I then want to simply call that function and pass in a array with a certain size, and then get the number of elements within that passed in array.

All of this is fine except for of course getting the number of elements in the array as it seems there isn't a simple way to calculate that. So I was wondering if it would be right just to use a std::vector instead for all this? The only problem with that is that it feels like kinda a waste as I don't need the additional functionality that a std::vector provides.

So I was wondering if it's worth it or is there another "better" way to do what I want to do?

Comment: yes, yes and yes. You don pay anything for the additional functionality. It's all free.

Comment: Why possible reason could you have for **not** using std::vector? Use std::vector.

Comment: I'm wondering if you use the term array like `std::array`, array in the C++ sense or any other definition thereof. That makes a lot of a difference.

Comment: *The only problem with that is that it feels like kinda a waste as I don't need the additional functionality that a std::vector provides* -- Very few programmers even care if a class has extra functionality that they will seldom use.  As long as the class fulfills what is being achieved, that's enough.  Also, if you had to code your own **working** vector class, by the time you're done, your class would be similar to, but more than likely, inferior in quality and efficiency than `std::vector`.

Comment: You're better off using vectors and avoid the headaches of dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely yes you should be using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for this. The "extra functionality" is all free. A `std::vector` is a *template* class so it won't even create the functions you don't use. Also the functions are trivial and inline so it won't even generate function calls, the compiler will strip away everything so the generated code will be nearly the same as if you had coded a built in dynamic array by hand.